# PHP: execute query via odbc on MS-SQL database

Tags: php, sql, pdo, odbc

From my PHP Skript I try to execute a query at a MS-SQL Database.
The connection can be established, but I got everytime error: "Segmentation fault".
What is the cause for this error?

the line which cause the error ist the FETCH statement!!

My PHP Code:

```
<?PHP
try
{
   $db = new PDO("odbc:ms-sql","<user>","<passwort>");

   $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
   echo"Connection established";
   echo"\n";
}
catch (PDOException $Exception)
{
    echo " No connection established.";
    echo"\n";
    echo $Exception->getMessage();
    exit(UNKNOWN);
}
try
{
    $query_result = $db->query(select * from dbo.TEST where MAKE_DATE LIKE '%2014-08%');
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

}
catch(Exception $Exceptionsql)
{
    echo " SQL-Query failed. \n\n";
    echo $Exceptionsql->getMessage();
    exit(UNKNOWN);
}

    $result = $query_result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

//close DB connection
$db = null;

var_dump($result);

?>
```

I guess that the string to execute the query is wrong.
I would be grateful if somebody could help me.

Comment: I don't write PHP these days. Don't you need quotes around the SQL passed to the query method. I'm pretty surprised that even parses.

Comment: Which line is causing the exception?  Segmentation faults are application buffer problems.  If the query was invalid, you would get some sort of ODBC or SQL related error; not a crash.